# Weak closure of orthonormal basis in Hilbert space (2)

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, orthonormal, nets, weak-topology

Let $E=\{e_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis in an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$. With help from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394763/weak-closure-of-orthonormal-basis-in-hilbert-space) I managed to prove that $E\cup\{0_{H}\}$ is contained in the weak closure of $E$. Is the reverse inclusion also true?

**My attempt to prove it:** If $x$ is in the weak closure of $E$, then there is a net $(x_i)$ in $E$ that converges weakly to $x$. So $x_{i}$ is of the form $e_{n_i}$ for some $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$. Weak convergence implies that $\langle e_{n_i},h\rangle\to\langle x,h\rangle$ for all $h\in H$. How do I proceed? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You know already that $\langle e_n,h\rangle\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So, as a subsequence, $\langle e_{n_i},h\rangle\to 0$ as $i\to\infty$ (or $n_i = k$ is constant for almost all $i$, in which case $e_{n_i}\to e_k$). So, $\langle x,h\rangle = 0$ for any $h\in H$, resulting in $x=0$.

Comment: But what if the index set $I$ has greater cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$? Can we then still say that the net $(e_{n_i})_{i\in I}$ is a subsequence of $(e_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$?

Comment: I think, since [Conway, Cor. V.4.4] your Hilbert space is separable, and thus sequentially complete, so nets are redundant.