# Riesz Representation Theorem & Weak closure of orthonormal basis in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, orthonormal, weak-topology

So [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394763/weak-closure-of-orthonormal-basis-in-hilbert-space) it was shown in an infinite dimensional seperable Hilbert space $H$, with the orthonormal basis $E=\{e_1,e_2,\dots \}$ that $0\in \overline{E}^w$, where the right hand side denotes the weak closure of $E$. Can someone explain how the Riesz Representation theorem is used here?

Comment: $0\in \overline{E}^w$ because $e_n \to 0$ weakly.

Comment: @geetha290krm so do we actually need Riesz representation here? That's the only place where I'm getting stuck

Comment: Well, $e_n \to 0$ because $ \langle x, e_n\rangle\to 0$ for all $x$ and every continuous linear functional on $H$ is given by an inner product with some $x$. So, yes, you need Riesz Theorem.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes of course, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Riesz Representation here. As shown in [Cameron's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3394805/22857), all you need is Bessel's inequality.